# Source code as settings file at runtime where/anywhere application run, without VS

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, winforms

I use **Settings.cs** as centralized ini-like file. You know C# is a new generation high level language and I wonder does it allow -some how- including source files. In ASPX environment it would be possible, but how about WPF & Winform applications?

Comment: C# is more than ten years old... =)

Comment: OUCH!!! I bet you're coming from a PHP background... Use the Visual Studio settings designer and access your settings through `Properties.Settings.Default.<SettingName>`!

Comment: I wonder could I open settings file at where the app. deployed. Security what? It's my own machine & my own code... Plus my own curiosity. Thorsten Dittmar you are right, I used PHP ages ago :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cftf714c(VS.90).aspx

In visual studio, click on settings.settings under your project in the solution explorer.

Comment: The answerer completely misread the question. I downvoted the 'incorrect' upvote.

Comment: My +1 comes from the fact that the feature as the OP requests it opens wide possibilities for both bugs and security breaches. The settings service fulfills what the OP seems to want, and is both much more secure and error-proof. So I don't see any answerer's fault, except perhaps too heavy usage of telepathy.

Comment: @Vlad: I agree with you, but that is NOT what was asked. If the OP wanted a lesson in best practices, he could have asked on programmers.stackexchange.com, where people can freely speak their correct or incorrect opinions. Also, how do you know the OP does not want the user to use operations and call methods? You are making assumptions with no backing information. Just saying :)

Comment: @leppie How is this not a "centralized ini-like file"?

Comment: @Brian Gordon: See my previous comment. You and Vlad are making a lot of assumptions that the OP may or may not want. Perhaps you/Vlad should ask the OP to clarify the requirement before assuming things.

Comment: @leppie: this is a matter of taste. In fact, I've seen a huge number of questions on this site, where the answerers needed to guess what is _really_ asked for, and to suggest a way completely different from the one implied by the question. IMHO this site is for helping people, and answering not literally the question, but trying to understand what is really needed provides much more help. Anyway, the OP could take part in the discussion, too.

Comment: @Leppie:  It allows for the same functionality that the OP asked for, while not being a security hole.  An ideal complete answer would include both .Settings and codedom approaches, but push the questioner to use the .Settings file.  SO would be useless if it boiled down to "just tell the questioner how to do whatever braindead thing they want and don't warn of the consequences."

Comment: Can I modify settings where the application deployed? In short; I don't want to repeat "modify and publish then install" cycle anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile source files at runtime using `CodeDom`.
You can read more about it here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655

Comment: If you do this, you're opening your application to a huge security hole. You've given people a way to execute abribrary code via your application, which I hope does not EVER run as anything but a non-privledged user

Comment: @Andy This is probably not a problem in most client applications.

Comment: I didn;t address in my answer to weather this is a good practice as a settings store. This however answered what he asked for.

Comment: @Variant, While it's splendid that you've given them a helpful and worthwhile answer, it'd probably be good if you -did- note that it's not very good practice, as well. =)

Comment: @Brian:  I disagree.  History is littered with insecure apps being explioted running under a non-privledged account to gain privledges.  IE is bashed on frequently because it runs ActiveX code from the web.  How is this any different?  Variant:  Yes you answered the question, but its also irresponsible to not point out potental problems with a solution when they exist, especially security related ones.

Comment: I agree as well, Applying this kind of solution should be made with extreme caution